# Converting existing function to handle multiple files to unzip

Tags: file, powershell, compression

I have an existing working code to unzip the file in gz format:

```
Function DeGZip-File{
    Param(
        $infile,
        $outfile = ($infile -replace '\.gz$','')
    )

    $input = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $inFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Open), ([IO.FileAccess]::Read), ([IO.FileShare]::Read)
    $output = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $outFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Create), ([IO.FileAccess]::Write), ([IO.FileShare]::None)
    $gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream $input, ([IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)

    $buffer = New-Object byte[](1024)
    while($true){
        $read = $gzipstream.Read($buffer, 0, 1024)
        if ($read -le 0){break}
        $output.Write($buffer, 0, $read)
    }
    $gzipStream.Close()
    $output.Close()
    $input.Close()
}
$infile="\\loction of the file\filename.gz"
DeGZip-File $infile
```

Is it possible to use this code to decompress all of the .gz files from the folder? And how would parameters look like to be passed to the script. I assume that now instead of the file name it should look for the input directory and destination folder.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -File | % { DeGZip-File $_ }`?

Comment: what about parameters supplied, I would think now it should be the path for the input files and destinations for output?

Comment: That wasn't part of the question. If your question, as written, isn't what you want to ask about then edit it to accurately represent what you actually want to ask.

Comment: @EtanReisner It is an odd question since it seems like he is looking for basic information [about functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx). While the question is a little unclear maybe I don't think an edit is required solely based on his commented response. I think the OP is just wondering how your comment satisfies his question which is what you tried to help with. Which is only useful with PowerShell 3.0 and maybe might be easier to understand as `Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.gz" | ForEach-Object{ DeGZip-File $_.FullName }`

Answer (score 1):

As it currently stands it only looks like you asking how to encorporate your function into a loop. Etan Reisner was trying to help you do just that. To build on his comment there are a couple of things you could do. This information is located in [about_functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx)

```
$path = "c:\temp\somepath"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "*.gz" | ForEach-Object{
    DeGZip-File -inifile $_.FullName
    # Or the following would also work
    # DeGZip-File $_.FullName
}
```

`-outfile` could be considered optional based on how you have your function set up. If you need to declare that with the function call then you would just be doing this in the loop

```
DeGZip-File -inifile $_.FullName -outfile "otherFileName"
```

or

```
DeGZip-File $_.FullName "SomehtingElse"
```

**Aside**

Consider looking into [Advanced Functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847806.aspx) and you can make your function accept pipeline input.

Comment: That works, and the way the function is written, you are absolutely right, I did not need the output file name defined. It is exactly the way I wanted. The only issue is, I want to write decompressed files to a different folder, and now it is in the same as the original compressed files.

Comment: @user3235631 If you want a different destination that simply define it with `-outfile`? with the `$_.Name` of the file in pipe.

Comment: I am not that proficient, and cannot understand how -outfile would work for multiple files

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you could simply incorporate your function into a ForEach-Object loop. Alternatively if you make two parameter sets, and in one leave it like you have it, and the other one accept pipeline values on your parameter, and make that parameter a `[FileInfo]` object, you could easily use `Get-ChildObject` to pipe to your function and not even have to use a loop. As for wanting your output in another folder, add a parameter to the function, and a little internal logic to accommodate that...

```
Function DeGZip-File{
[cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Piped')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Direct')][String]$infile,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Direct')][String]$outfile = ($infile -replace '\.gz$',''),
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Piped',ValueFromPipeline=$true)][System.IO.FileInfo[]]$PipedFile,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Piped')]$Redirect=$null,
        [Switch]$PassThru
    )

Process{
    If($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Piped'){
        $infile = $PipedFile.FullName
        $outfile = If([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Redirect)){$infile -replace '\.gz$',''}else{Join-Path $Redirect -ChildPath ($PipedFile.BaseName)}
    }

    $inputfile = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $inFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Open), ([IO.FileAccess]::Read), ([IO.FileShare]::Read)
    $output = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $outFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Create), ([IO.FileAccess]::Write), ([IO.FileShare]::None)
    $gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream $inputfile, ([IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)

    $buffer = New-Object byte[](1024)

    $read = $gzipstream.Read($buffer, 0, 1024)
    Do{
        $output.Write($buffer, 0, $read)
        $read = $gzipstream.Read($buffer, 0, 1024)
    }While($read -gt 0)

    $gzipStream.Close()
    $output.Close()
    $inputfile.Close()

    If($PassThru){[System.IO.FileInfo]$outfile}
    }
}
```

I also added a `-PassThru` switch in case you want to see the files that it extracted.

**Edit:** I forgot to include a usage example, my bad...

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\GZippedFiled\*.gz" | DeGZip-File -Redirect "C:\Temp\Unzipped" -PassThru
```

That will unzip all of the .GZ files in the "C:\Temp\GZippedFiled" folder, and will write the decompressed files with the same (minus .gz) file name in the "C:\Temp\Unzipped" folder. It will also show you the files that it extracts, displaying the [fileinfo] object for each (Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, and Name). Or you could do it more simply and just pipe to the function without any parameters, and it would extract them in place and not output anything to the console.

It also accepts the old style of usage, ala:

```
DeGZip-File -infile "C:\Path\To\File.gz" -outfile "C:\Path\To\NewFile.ext"
```

**Edit2:** Ok, just to make sure I understand the issue in your comment. Let us say that you have 2 files compressed:

```
C:\Temp\Resume.docx.gz
C:\Temp\Cover Letter.docx.gz
```

You want to unzip them, and store the resultant files in `C:\Temp\Unzipped` (the destination folder should already exist). Your script should have the function up top, then you can define paths if so desired, and then pipe `Get-ChildItem` to the function. It should look something like this:

```
Function DeGZip-File{
    <function code goes here>
}

$FullPath = 'C:\Temp\'
$DestinationPath = 'C:\Temp\Unzipped'

Get-ChildItem -Path $fullpath -Filter "*.gz" | DeGZip-File -Redirect $destinationpath -PassThru
```

I literally just copied the function from this answer to a fresh PowerShell ISE instance, put 2 .gz files in my C:\Temp folder, created a C:\Temp\Unzipped folder, and ran that code above. It functioned perfectly. The files extracted, and it showed me the details of them as it did it. The trailing backslash on the path doesn't matter, either, both, or neither of the paths could have or not have the backslash at the end and it won't make a difference because of `join-path` sterilizing it.

Comment: Tried it and failed. New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "4" argument(s): "Empty path name is not legal." on the line where $inputfile = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $inFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Open), ([IO.FileAccess]::Read), ([IO.FileShare]::Read)

Comment: I used the function just as it is before posting it, and just tested it again just now. How exactly did you call it?

Comment: The first method. But I just thought of something. The function definition should probably be located before the call.. I will make a change and post the result

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Path $fullpath -Filter "*.gz" | DeGZip-File -Redirect $destinationpath -PassThru. No avail, the same error. I have function defined first, then listed all parameters defined for the path and destination.

Comment: Okay, that is exactly how I have it. The only difference is, that I populate the fullpath and destination path from several variables. Let me provide the full listing of the code, I wonder if you can copy and paste it again and see if it works on your machine. Thanks.

Comment: Run your script, and then do a simple `Get-ChildItem -path $fullpath` and see if it returns anything at all. If it does, try filtering for `'*.gz'` and see if that returns anything. If it does, then I'm not sure what to tell you.